Load and process data simultaneously - Python
I have a huge amount of data to process through, and some IO limitations. Ultimately, reading and writing the data takes about the same amount of total time as processing the data. However, while I can parallelize the data processing, I cannot parallelize the IO.
Is there a decent way I can multithread a python process where I spend one of my threads loading the data and the rest of them reading and operating on it, asynchronously?
Say I have L (load) and P (process) and each of those comes in a block. Would it be more efficient to have a thread going:
LLLLLLL
and another simultaneously running
PPPPPPP
as fast as it can go? Or would it ultimately end up being equally fast to have parallel blocks going
LP LP LP LP?
Problems with the latter approach seem (a) that it ends up potentially gating every single process behind a much slower L, especially if the computer tries to load all of them at the same time, which means dividing a constant IO among multiple threads, and (b) doesn't allow me to divvy up the work by the relative proportion of work. For example, if I end up doing more to the data and it takes 3x longer to process each chunk as it does to load it, I'd want to put 3x more threads on the processing side. (c) I don't ever want periods where some L isn't going on, but you could theoretically imagine that happening in the LP parallel form where everything is working on P at a given point in time.
It may end up that these concerns are minimal and the ease of doing a LP block configuration is easier from a readability perspective. But I really just don't know very well.
Thanks!

https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles/ as referenced here: https://github.com/python/asyncio/wiki/ThirdParty#filesystem

It sounds like a good approach would be to load the data one batch at a time, and queue it up in an appropriate data structure, you can have a bunch of work processes (one or more) take data from that queue and process it.
This ensures that the data is loaded sequentially and that, as soon as data is available, a worker can get to work on processing it, while the reading process can continue to read the next batch.
If you're right and loading takes the same amount of time as processing, a single worker would be enough. If loading is faster, you can add workers if your computer has the resources to run multiple in parallel.
The worker would have to be a separate process to truly run in parallel. But since you're parallelizing with I/O, you may be able to just write an asynchronous solution, which allows your application to work on processing while it waits for the I/O to complete. An asynchronous solution is likely easier to write and takes fewer resources in overhead. A multiprocessing solution is needed if you need multiple workers running in parallel, or perhaps if your I/O process actually does more than just basic I/O.
